# Preventing Redshift SQL Injection

Tags: java, postgresql, sql-injection, mybatis, amazon-redshift

I have the unfortunate situation where I have to build up a SQL string by concatenating strings - the classic SQL injection scenario. I **can't** use prepared statements.

If I escape the `'` character am I safe? Or are there other attack vectors?

I'm using MyBatis and it's `${}` notation (vs `#{}` that generates prepared statements). I have **no choice** with this - it has to be `${}`. I can't use prepared statements.

EDIT:

To add a little more clarity; it's an [ASW Redshift UNLOAD command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html). The first parameter for UNLOAD is a SQL string.

Comment: Will it save you from `; DROP TABLE --`?

Comment: Escaping `'` is insufficient. There are other attack vectors. You're tying both hands and feet then asking the best way to win the fight.

Comment: Can just any random user run `unload` against your database on AWS? It's documented to accept a `select` statement as the first arg. Will it also accept DDL or `delete` statements? Will it accept multiple SQL statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Given that you cannot do it the correct way because of restrictions in Redshift):

On PostgreSQL with `standard_conforming_strings` set to `on` *all* you need to do is double quotes, making `'` into `''`. That's it.

Backslashes aren't significant unless `standard_conforming_strings` is off or you use an `E''` string. If either of those things are true then you have to do backslash escaping instead.

As Redshift is based on a fork of an ancient PostgreSQL version I don't know for sure how this applies to it. Reading the documentation on its lexical structure and syntax would be wise, to verify that it is consistent with how PostgreSQL works.

Answer (score 1):

[`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)) really is the way to go. In one fell swoop you eliminate a big pile of work and risk regarding [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) hackers.

If you absolutely can’t/won’t use `PreparedStatement`, then you need to read about various strategies. You'll have to write a bunch of checks to examine and modify your inputs and SQL. No [silver bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_bullet). (Well, actually, `PreparedStatement` *is* your silver bullet. But no *other* silver bullet.)

Google for items like "sanitize sql input". You will find resources such as:

- [Bobby-Tables.com](http://bobby-tables.com)  (which tells you to use PreparedStatement).
- [Mitigation section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Mitigation) of Wikipedia page on SQL Injection.
- Article, [Prevent Web Attacks Using Input Sanitization](http://www.esecurityplanet.com/browser-security/prevent-web-attacks-using-input-sanitization.html).
- Article, [How to prevent SQL injection attacks?](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/sql-injection-prevention/), that explains with examples how sanitizing input is not enough, and recommends using … yes, you guessed it: `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: It's an AWS Redshift UNLOAD, which insists on the first parameter been a SQL string.

Comment: What it looks like is that my choices are - be open to SQL injection; or don't use UNLOAD.

Comment: No, I suggest 3 options: (1) be wide open to SQL Injection by doing nothing, (2) moderate your risk without eliminating all risk by studying articles such as those listed above to implement multiple sanitizing checks, and (3) use PreparedStatement so you can sleep soundly.

Comment: @BasilBourque: How wide open the OP is depends on whether a) any user can run `unload`, or only a database superuser, b) whether `unload` will reject multiple SQL statements, c) whether `unload` will reject DML, insert, update, and delete statements (reasonable, given that its name is `unload`), and d) I don't know, but surely I've forgotten something. The OP needs to test these things.